# uploading an object model on roboearth.org using API

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to ask about the steps of uploading an object model on RoboEarth.org
as shown:
[image: image description]

,but when searched for the already uploaded object models ,I have found that their are kinectmodel.zip  , 2dcammodel_zip files uploaded too , so should I upload them ?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47897/uploading-an-object-model-on-roboearth.org-using-api/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The uploading steps is written in [roboearth tutorial document](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth/Tutorials/Record%20an%20object%20model#Uploading_the_model_to_the_RoboEarth_Database).

In this tutorial, you can upload the object you just record by using record_gui, I don't think you need to upload kinectmodel.zip , 2dcammodel_zip files.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-11-11**:
I have a problem in RoboEarth stack , so I wanted to try uploading object models using RoboEarth Server " [www.roboearth.org](http://www.roboearth.org) "

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-11**:
Is the problem you met close to these two?
http://answers.ros.org/question/47981/errors-in-stacks-in-ros/
http://answers.ros.org/question/47765/ros-stacks-in-home-and-file-system/

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-11-12**:
yes,it is the nearly the same problem of mine..